# How to get server error when a FIRStorageUploadTask fails with FIRStorageErrorCodeUnknown?

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-storage

Refer to this [Firebase doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/ios/upload-files). In part, it has this cryptic note:

```
uploadTask.observe(.failure) { snapshot in
  if let error = snapshot.error as? NSError {
    switch (StorageErrorCode(rawValue: error.code)!) {
    ...
    case .unknown:
      // Unknown error occurred, inspect the server response
      break
    default:
      // A separate error occurred. This is a good place to retry the upload.
      break
    }
  }
}
```

Great! I'd love to see the server error. But how do I do that? The error returns a code -13000 (FIRStorageErrorCodeUnknown) and an error string of "An unknown error occurred, please check the server response."

So how does one get the server error response???

Comment: One option might be to set a breakpoint in the Xcode debugger and go up the call stack.

Comment: @PaulBeusterien Thats not a bad idea, but what happens is that we have thousands of devices in the field, and get this occasionally. During my own testing it never triggers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the source, there is additional detail in the NSDictionary object available on the NSError as `error.userInfo`.

For example, see https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/blob/master/FirebaseStorage/Sources/FIRStorageUploadTask.m#L204

Comment: I put in a log of logging, now seeing what's going on, and this was a big help! For anyone else hitting this, the method producing most of my errors is this one: + (nullable NSError *)errorWithServerError:(nullable NSError *)error reference:(nullable FIRStorageReference *)reference {... - The key in the UserInfo is kFIRStorageResponseBody -> "ResponseBody"